# Is there's any possible way to show both positive and negative numbers in vis-timeline time axis instead of defualt date given by the Library

Tags: angular, typescript, timeline, vis.js, vis-timeline

Is there's any possible way to show both positive and negative numbers in vis-timeline instead of default date given by the Library

I was trying to implement a timeline which starts from a negative number (-20) and ends with a Positive number (20). By Default vis-time line time axis only supports for Date Formats, in both major and minor labels in time axis for vis-timeline

I am trying to implement this timeline using Angular

Here are the current configurations given to timeline

```
// time line options
  getOptions() {
    this.options = {
      start: moment().subtract(10, 'm').toISOString(),
      end: moment().add(40, 'm').toISOString(),
      max: new Date(2023, 10, 21),
      min: new Date(2023, 8, 20),
      timeAxis: { scale: 'minute', step: 1 },
      zoomMax: 900000,
      zoomMin: 60000, // 1 min
    };
  }
```

[vis-timeline Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vis-timeline)
[vis-timeline Documentation](https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/)

A possible way to show both positive and negative numbers in vis-timeline instead of default date given by the Library